# How do I redirect to apps.facebook.com/example from example.com?

Tags: facebook, redirect

I bought my domain from domain.com and now I pay $360pa for inmotionhosting VPS. I just bought SSL for my website for another $125 so I could set up example.com as https://example.com as a legitimate Facebook App.

This was my intention. Maybe I was an idiot.

I want visitors to example.com to arrive at apps.facebook.com/example. This is my website. Naked, it's not good enough.

My nameservers from domain.com point to inmotionhosting.com where my files and database are located. You can only visit by going to example.com.

So how do I have my visitors type 'example.com' in their browser and arrive at apps.facebook.com/example when the entirety of my site is inside that app?

It's either easy or impossible. Maybe the https has given me new powers that I'm not aware of. I know I could set up my canvas files on a different website (its going to be cloaked anyway), but I don't think my https will work without the relevant website. I don't want to wait another week or pay another $125.

So,

How do I redirect to apps.facebook.com/example from example.com?

Comment: I'm guessing I'll need to make an index.html file that says 'redirect ONLY if you're not at apps.facebook.com/example'. Am I right?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your VPS is a Linux box:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained the pertinent parts of that page. As soon as that page changes / goes away, this answer becomes useless.